# How to update data with .transaction while maintaining priority?

Tags: transactions, firebase

I did not find any documentation on how update a value in Firebase using '.transaction' while also maintaining priority like '.setWithPriority' does. I have this working but just looking for some feedback on best practices with Firebase API. Here is a snippet of the code I am working with:

```
userScoreRef.once('value', function(snapshot) 
{
    if(snapshot.val() === null) {
        // Create a new participant.
        userScoreRef.setWithPriority({ Participant: participant, CurrentScore: 0 }, 0);             
    }
    else {
        // Update participant score.
        userScoreRef.child("CurrentScore").transaction(function(_currentScore) {
        _currentScore++;
        userScoreRef.setWithPriority({ Participant: participant, CurrentScore: _currentScore }, _currentScore);
        return;})// DO NOT UPDATE WITH TRANSACTION! Let setWithPriority perform the data update.
    }
})
```

As you can see I am:
1) Pulling the current value from Firebase w/ .transaction, 2) using .setWithPriority to set the data, finally 3) simply returning on the transaction call to cancel it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently somewhat awkward, but something like the following should work:

```
userScoreRef.transaction(function(user) {
  if (user == null) {
    return {
      Participant: participant,
      CurrentScore: 0,
      '.priority': 0
    }
  } else {
    user.CurrentScore++;
    user['.priority'] = user.CurrentScore;
    return user;
  }
});
```

Basically, you can add .priority to the object you return from a transaction to set the priority.  But unfortunately, there is no way to get the current priority in your transaction update function.  Fortunately in your case, you don't need it, since it's just CurrentScore.